# Removing elements to new order email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

[image]

Given the image above, How can i remove the highlighted element above on my new order email? i tried removing it via local xml      didnt work. Any help wpuld be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are backend settings that control the price display in order emails. See if changing those help:

1. Go to `System > Configuration` and go to the tab `Sales > Tax`.
2. There, find the section `Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings` and check if any of the dropdowns have been set to `Including and Excluding Tax`.
3. If there are, select the one that says `Including Tax`.

See the screenshot for reference. Hope this helps.

[image: Tax settings]

Comment: Thank you for your  reply, It didnt give me the same output as what i wanted